# Link errors on Snow Leopard

Tags: c++, qt, poco

I creating a small desktop application using Qt and Poco on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Qt works fine, but once I started linking with Poco I get the following warning:

```
ld: warning: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.8.dylib, file is not of required architecture
```

Also when I link against the 10.5 SDK:

```
ld: warning: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.8.dylib, file is not of required architecture
```

Any hints on how to solve this?

**Solved!**

Here's my workaround (I also posted it on the Poco forums btw):

The problem is that when the architecture is not specified Snow Leopard defaults to 64-bit, while older versions of the OS default to 32-bit. In the Poco build system, the Darwin config file does not specify the architecture, so it picks 32 bit. My solution was to copy the Darwin_x86_64 config file over the Darwin file and replace the textual instances of 'x86_64' with 'i386'. This forces a 32 bit build.

A somewhat hackish solution though, let me know if it can be done in a cleaner way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you pull down the libraries from somewhere?  Poco comes with all the source.  Recompile it.

Comment: Specifically, recompile it for the desired architecture and choose the needed one when compiling with `-arch`.

Comment: You can check the architecture of a binary file with the lipo command. (lipo -info /path/to/binary)

Comment: @gf: I pulled the SVN branch and built it from scratch. @Dan: Thanks! The architecture is: x86_64. I probably need to make a 386 build, I think..

Comment: @Duck: running configure with config=Darwin still causes x86_64 builds to be created. I posted on the Poco forums about this.